# xtab error undefined columns selected

Tags: r

```
x = data.frame(a=c(T,F))
x['foo'] = c(T,F)
lm(foo ~ ., data = x)  # works
lm(. ~ foo, data = x)  # fails
xtab(. ~ foo, data = x)  # fails
```

The last line is the one I really want but it throws an "undefined columns selected" error. I need to set the dimension of `x` how I'm doing it because the name of the dimension comes from a variable.

I've been messing with this for a while now and can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This function is simply not set up to be able to use a period in the formula. For whatever reason, they decided not to resolve the formula terms in the data frame context. What exactly do you need to work? You can build a formula dynamically.

Comment: Also i was assuming you were using `xtab` from the "prettyR" package. When using a non-default package, you should include the `library()` statement in your sample code to make it clear.

Comment: C'mon. The function is named `xtabs`. (and it doesn't take a dot argument on hte LHS.) Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to `xtabs` from base R, turn your formula around so that the `.` is on the right of `~`

```
> xtabs(foo ~ ., data = x)
# a
# FALSE  TRUE 
#     0     1 
> xtabs(a ~ ., data = x)
# foo
# FALSE  TRUE 
#     0     1
```

And the same goes for `lm`